# How to launch xAPI course hosted on cloud scorm from an LMS?

Tags: scorm, xapi, scorm-cloud-api

I have an LMS and I want to launch courses that are hosted on cloud scorm from this lms, for example the user in the lms should click a link to launch a course that is hosted on scorm cloud.
I read about dispatch function in scorm cloud which generates a file that should be saved then I can run this file to launch the course but this wont work for me because there is no automatic function to generate the dispatch and run it when the user click the link.
Is there a way to create a link for launching in scorm cloud?

Comment: Do you need SSO?

Comment: So SCORM and xAPI are two different specs, and if you follow SCORM, you can almost never really follow xAPI. However, if you like the SCORM package structure, you should be able to convert to an xAPI course using this conversion tool: https://github.com/adlnet/SCORM-to-xAPI-Wrapper. \n 
SCORM cloud was built to host SCORM courses, and when the xAPI specification became adopted, they also created an LRS (which is why many xAPI users leverage it).
Really if you have an LMS, the best thing to look for is a plugin that enables the use of SCORM and host it there.

Comment: @Flotolk Thank you, this plugin would make my platform able to launch xAPI or SCORM courses? without the plugin "launching" is unpossible? plugin like Rustici engine you mean?

Comment: @Dr.Noob I do not know what platform you are using so I can not really give you much advice on what plugins are available. Additionally, there is no course packaging or launching requirements in the xAPI specification, but many courses use xAPI Launch logic.

Comment: I am actually using  just a normal website which is not an official LMS and I want to be able to launch xAPI contents on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't need SSO between the LMS and SCORM Cloud, the way to do this is to use a public URL: https://support.scorm.com/hc/en-us/articles/206164296-How-to-generate-a-public-URL-

If you do need SSO and your LMS supports SCORM, then the best way is probably to use Dispatch. You say in your question that you can't use Dispatch, which may suggest that your LMS does not support SCORM?

If you need SSO and your LMS does not support SCORM, then it would be useful to know what your LMS *does* support.

Comment: Thanks for your response, the LMS that I'm using doesn't support xAPI nor SCORM, what is the difference between  when a platform supports xAPI, SCORM and when it doesn't?

Comment: SCORM and xAPI are specifications defining a common way of doing things. To use an analogy, think of plug sockets - you might have British sockets or American sockets - those are different shapes of plug and voltage etc. Sounds like perhaps your LMS is a bit like just having an exposed wire that you can twist wires into or something!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, since I can Launch an xAPI course or SCORM course by using public URL as the link you added, why do I need to make the platform "support" xAPI or scorm?

Answer (score 1):

To launch a SCORM Cloud course [in SCORM or xAPI format] from a static, non-SCORM website you can use some of the following options:

1. you can use public invitation [as Andrew describes].   You will get a static link that you can put on your site.   Some downsides to this:
   A. there is no integration of the data.  You will not be able to tell in your "LMS" if a learner took the course.
   B. you have no mechanism to control access to the content.   A learner can share the link with his or her 1M instagram followers, and you will be financially liable for that registration volume.
2. you can create a launch URL via the SCORM Cloud api, which will take some server-side work and is an undertaking of some complexity.
3. if you are using WordPress, there is a free integration called the SCORM Cloud plugin for WordPress.
4. for a commercial integration of SCORM Cloud with WordPress or Drupal, there is the Bright plugin, [https://bright.aura-software.com/], which also directly integrates with LearnDash LMS as well as WooCommerce.

Dispatch will not be an option for you as your website is not SCORM-capable.

These solutions are progressively capable in generally ascending order.

You will probably get good mileage from asking SCORM Cloud directly, if you go to their website that have their "ask us anything" link [https://rusticisoftware.com/ask-andy/] and they are very helpful.